# "professions' and "occupations" what's the differnce?

Tags: meaning

"professions' and "occupations" difference

"Transborder activities and the general dynamics that 
they produce can be performed by socioeconomic categories, such as professions, occupations, or classes,"

Answer (score 1):

> **occupation** --> to occupy ones time i.e. seamstress or blacksmith
>
> **profession** --> publicly declared and certified occupation i.e. master
>   blacksmith or master seamstress

References from the OSX dictionary

> **profession** |prəˈfeSHən| noun **1** a paid occupation, esp. one that
>   involves prolonged training and a formal qualification:

-

> **occupation** |ˌäkyəˈpāSHən| noun **1** a job or profession: **2** the action,
>   state, or period of occupying or being occupied by military force:

[Goolge Search Link to Etymology of profession](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=profession%20etymology&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ygJAU9OJDomA7Qbaw4HABQ)

[image: Goole Etymology of profession]

Answer (score -1):

The sentence isn't very well written, but since it isn't yours (I presume), you can't revise it. To answer your question, the difference is largely one of education. "Professions" are followed by people with academic qualifications: doctors, lawyers, accountants, engineers, etc. "Occupations" are done by unqualified or semi-qualified people, such as traders, manual labourers, factory workers, drivers.

Comment: really? why? reference?

Comment: Everyday usage.